# MongoDB data modelling - Indexes and PK

Tags: c#, mongodb, data-modeling, nosql

I'm currently transitioning from an RDBMS to a NoSQL solution, more specifically MongoDB. Consider the following tables in my database (the original solution is much more complex, but I include this so you have an idea):

- User (PK_ID_User, FirstName, LastName, ...);
- UserProfile: (PK_ID_UserProfile, ProfileName, FK_ID_User, ...);

The keys in this table are GUIDs, however they are custom generated. For example:

- UserGUIDs will be of the following structure: US022d717e507f40a6b9551f11ebf2fcb4 (so, US-prefix and random numbers), 
  while UserProfile GUIDS will be of this format: UP0025f5804a30483b9b769c5707b02af6 (so UP-prefix and random numbers)

Now, suppose I want to convert this RDBMS data model to NoSQL MongoDB. For my application (which uses the C# driver), it is very important that all of document properties in MongoDB have the same name. This also counts for the ID fields: the names PK_ID_User and PK_ID_UserProfile, including the GUIDs, have to be the same.

Now, MongoDB uses a standard unique indexed property _id for storing id's. The name of this _id fields can ofcourse not be changed, even though I really need for my application to preserve the column / property names.

So I came up with the following document structures for my Users and User Profiles. Bear in mind that, for this case, I chose to use referenced data modeling over embeds for various reasons I won't explain here:
User-document

```
{
_id: ObjectId, - indexed
PK_ID_User: custom GUID, - indexed, as it needs to be unique
FirstName: string,
...
}
UserProfile-document
{
_id: ObjectId - indexed
PK_ID_UserProfile: custom GUID, as explained above - indexed, as it needs to be unique,
...
}
```

And here's the C# class:

```
  public class User
  {
    [BsonConstructor]
    public User() { }

    [BsonId] // the _id field
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("PK_ID_User")]
    public string PK_ID_User { get; set; }

    //Other Mapper properties
  }
```

The reason I chose this modelling strategy is the following: the current project consists of a whole web service, using ORM and RDBMS, and a client side that more or less maps the database objects to client side view objects. So it's really necessary to preserve the names of the Ids / PKs as much as possible. I decided that it'd be best to let MongoDB use the ObjectId's internally (for CRUD-operations), as they don't cause performance overhead, and use the custom GUIDs so they are compatible with the rest of my code. This way, minimal changes have to be made, MongoDB is happy and I am happy, as externally, I can keep querying results based on my GUID PKs that will always be unique. **As in MongoDB, my PK GUIDs are stored as unique strings, I think I don't have to worry about GUID overhead on the server side: the GUIDs are created by my C# application.**

However, I have my doubts about performance, I now always have a minimum of 2 indexes per document / collection, and have no idea how costly it is in terms of performance.

Is there a better approach for my problem, or should I stick to my current solution?

Kind regards.

Comment: I cannot really answer since I don't know much C# these days but GUIDs are not just expensive to make but also to query and store. Just because they are being made in your application does not nullify the penalty of using them

Answer (score 0):

> I now always have a minimum of 2 indexes per document / collection, and have no idea how costly it is in terms of performance.

Indexes cost performance for inserts and updates, and you posted no info on the frequency of write operations or your setup. It'll be impossible to give a definite answer without a measurement.

Then again, provided you're using a web application, I'd say the sheer network delay to your clients will be several *orders of magnitude* higher than the difference between say 1, 2 or 3 indexes, since all these operations *mostly* hit the RAM.

What's costly is the writing to disk, not the restructuring of the BTree in memory. Of course, having more and more indexes will increase the likelihood of an insert leading to costly restructuring of an index tree that would have to hit the disk, but that also depends on the structure of the keys themselves.

If anything, I'd worry about bad cache coherence and time-locality of GUIDs: If your data were very time-local (like logs), then a GUID might hurt (high jitter at the beginning of the string), because updates would be more likely to rearrange entire sub-trees and a typical time-range query would grab items cluttered throughout the tree. But since this appears to be about users and user profiles, such a query would probably not make much sense.